# scan for and delete specific files using PS

Tags: powershell

I have a script that I am using to do an upgrade.  We are finding that after the upgrade there is an ini file remaining in several User directories (Win7).  We are able to go to each computer and in elevated cmd prompt and use a `del /s "filename.ini"` (without quotes obviously).  This is going to be way too much work as there are 800-900 PCs.  Was trying to add a line in the script to find and delete those files, not working....

The PC names are in a csv file, so there is a variable to point to that file:

```
# Read "Computers.csv" to get list of computers to upgrade.

$Computers = Get-Content Computers.csv

# Execute the upgrade process on computers in "Computers.csv sequentely.

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
```

Then Was trying to add this line:

```
foreach ($termreg in $termregs) {
    remove-item $termreg.fullname
}
```

where the file is:

```
$termreg = gci $UsersPath -Recurse | Where {$_.name -like "test.txt"}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: According to your code snippets you store the file list in the variable `$termreg`, then use the *same* variable as the loop variable when iterating over a variable `$termregs`. For further help you need to elaborate on the "not working" part. *What* is "not working"? How *exactly* is it "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see exactly what you are doing wrong with your script because parts are out of order or missing. Here's one approach:

```
#This isn't a properly formatted csv if you are using Get-Content rather than Import-CSV
$Computers = Get-Content Computers.csv
#Invoke-Command runs in parallel when provided multiple systems to run on
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -Scriptblock {
    #Use gwmi if not PS3+, can use -filter to exclude users
    $UserDirectories = Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty LocalPath
    foreach ($UserDirectory in $UserDirectories) {
        Get-ChildItem $UserDirectory -Recurse -Include "test.txt" |
            Remove-Item -Force
    }
}
```